# Can we make some inline code clickable?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Thinking about most Questions, they are tagged with a specific programming language.

I think it would be possible to link short `code` automaticly to the official documentation, if we know the specific programming language.

**Often I say for example:**

Take a look at [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) or [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php)

**For this i current write:**

```
Take a look at <a href="http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php">`PDO`</a> or <a href="http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php">`file_get_contents`</a>
```

**Better would be this:**

```
Take a look at `PDO` or `file_get_contents`
```

**Summary**

For me this would be a nice feature. The implementation should not be so hard. Thinking about some standard url format and playing with `404` and `200` Headers. What do you think about?

Comment: Any reason you don't use markdown for your links? `[PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)` ?

Comment: This also works: ``[`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)`` => [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While yes, this would be a cool feature, it seems to be way too difficult to actually implement.

1. Many questions are tagged with more than one language
2. The documentation is not always organized well enough to facilitate automatic linking
3. It would be a lot of extra server load to look up those URLs

Even in the example you posted, one is a link to a book, and the second is to a specific function reference, yet they are formatted the same way.

Comment: Not to mention that auto linking would need to take versions into account. The Python 3 versions of many functions differ materially from their Python 2 counterparts for example. Good luck linking to the correct documentation when talking about porting code between the major versions!