# "The candidates answer your questions.", different elections, same link

Tags: bug, moderator-election, broken-link

Being in the election period of the moderators, I wanted to read the answers to the questionnaires of past elections.
So I went to the page of the previous election: 
[2017 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9)
.

At the bottom of the article, I saw the link "**The candidates answer your questions.**"
But, to my surprise, I arrived on the answers to the [2018 questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364498/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).

This seems to be the case for all election pages.

Is this a "bug"? It looks like a template that would be the same for all these pages.

The pages still exist, and can easily be found with a little [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Belection%5D+%5Bdiscussion%5D+moderator+election+questionnaire).

Comment: @rene yeah... https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions

Comment: Interesting link @JonClements. The title and side informations changes. Could this link also be dynamic?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381115/1364007

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is only one election Post in the database, [postid 8041931](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions) and it is revised when the next election takes place. Looking at the results of a previous election doesn't fetch the valid revision for that moment.

If you're curious, you can look at the revision history as shown by Jon Clements to find the exact text that was valid during the election you're interested in.

You can use this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/824608) to roughly find which election number had which text. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to add links to the actual revisions (because that gets frigging complex).

Comment: Interstingly, the corresponding page to edit (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/edit) is available to everyone and actually allows you to edit. But when you try to submit the edit, it says "An error occurred submitting the edit".

Comment: LOL, let's not try to break the system @DonaldDuck ...

Comment: LOL @DonaldDuck I clicked the link and was greeted with a white screen with a single line of text "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes."

Comment: I like that the 8041931 post has a score of 1 indicating that someone has somehow upvoted it... (the other posts of that type are all 0)

Comment: @DavidG Do you have a list of the other posts of that type? I would be curious to see their revision history and things like that. Also, how did you see the 8041931 post's score?

Comment: @DonaldDuck It's from the SEDE query rene linked above.

Comment: @DonaldDuck interestingly also, the revision history shows an edit from someone who was not a mod, neither an employee: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions revision 31

Comment: @fedorqui [That user was a moderator when the edit was made.](http://web.archive.org/web/20170713071459/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks)

Comment: @DonaldDuck oh! I had checked his profile and did not find the _sheriff_ badge, so I assumed he had not been. But you are right, and I see he was a elected on [election 6 - Spring 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6)