# Is it responsible to open moderator voting up to know-nothings like me?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderators

I have absolutely no business voting for moderators. I know almost nothing about any of these people and so would be likely basing my decision on arbitrary impressions like avatar, how similar they seem to me, cool factor, and other factors that have no clear relevance.

I don't think that's because I'm a bad person, or stupid, or anything like that. I think it's because I'm pretty normal.

Is it any better to trust the judgment of a bunch of normies like me, or leave it up to the judgment of people who are way more invested and knowledgeable?

I'm inclined to think it's the latter.

Comment: You don't think the [Meta Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364498/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1) is relevant?

Comment: You might end-up with an elected moderator that is going to burninate [tag:javascript] ...

Comment: I don't follow @rene.

Comment: By not voting you trust my vote and as you don't follow my comments do you still think it is wise to not invest a little bit of time so you can make your own judgement call and vote informed instead of leaving it to me, the unguided missile?

Comment: My first impression is that I wouldn't trust your vote because of the difficulty I'm having following your logic. (It's not personal as I don't know you).

Comment: @rene  'burninate javascript'?  Is that a possibility?  Who advocates that, and where can I vote for them?

Comment: @MartinJames might need bribery ...

Comment: *I wouldn't trust your vote* ... well, then make sure you vote for yourself, despite being a *know-nothings* (I'm not sure why people say such things about theirselves). There is plenty of time to read-up on the candidates and make an informed vote for yourself.

Comment: My wife just had a baby. I have very little time. But whether or not I'm capable, who really is doing that? Do you think it's most people? I don't.

Comment: Such is the burden of a democracy, participants are expected to have done their homework to be sufficiently informed or take on the responsibility to not cast a random vote when they are not.  If you don't want to be responsible then it still is not a problem when the majority are.

Comment: Are you proposing an alternative? How is Stack Overflow supposed to tell whether you're a well-informed voter or voting randomly?

Comment: @meagar a while ago [Atwood proposed to introduce "citizenship level"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/165773), that possibly could be an alternative

Comment: I mean, consider the consequences. Say a large group of "normies" (seriously...) elects a particular moderator that happens to be really bad at the job and even abuses their power. What will happen? That person will quickly cease to be a moderator, that's what. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Jut read the Q/A and decide who you agree with the most. If you don't agree with neither, then don't vote. There's absolutely no need to judge them by their Avatar or "cool factor".

Comment: @gnat Having a citizen score would help with plenty of things, but I'm not sure if it solves this particular problem.  It would help a lot in getting a feel for how qualified a candidate is, as it has the potential to be more useful than any of the other current stats shown, but a user who does the kinds of things that are suggested for that citizen score wouldn't indicate whether someone was an informed voter.  Someone can be a good citizen but just not be familiar with the candidates and not do their research on them before voting on them (and vice versa).

Comment: I mean... i'm sure i'd qualify under any citizenship level or criteria to be allowed to vote given my participation, doesn't necessarily mean i'd put much effort into casting my vote based on reasons that are important.

Comment: @arame3333:  You should read my answer; it does explain that you don't *have* to remain in the dark on a candidate if you don't choose to.

Comment: @MartinJames: normally I'd vote for an anti-JavaScript candidate, but they keep making Promises they have no intention of fulfilling.

Comment: “I don't think that's because I'm a bad person, or stupid, or anything like that.” Neither do I. But can we really be sure?

Answer (score -10, accepted):

The guy you choose gets some more rights to do stuff **he is already doing** (all of them are).

Your responsibility is to not choose right or wrong, but to choose the one suiting you the best. Democracy = you are given a choice, choose or not.

If you don't know anyone (never met them or seen their comments, actions, etc.) then it worth to read their background and judge them "I want"/"I don't want".

I've cast upvotes to some of those with similar interests (e.g. `C#`), so I am *probably* gaining something for myself (other answerer calls them janitors, hell yeah) ;)

I've cast several downvotes also, mainly subjectively, where I don't believe what candidates would be good, e.g. if guy seems too young = less responsibility, or if something among his words didn't catch me.

Comment: Hmm about your comment on age, I would argue that age does not equal responsibility. In fact, one of the most responsible, level headed guys on the network I know is also one of the youngest I know.

Comment: IIRC, BoltClock started modding for us when he was a teen. One of the best mods I've seen on network, IMHO. Another really awesome user, under 13 and a mod (set something up through their parents to ensure they could use the site legally. No idea if this user is still under 13.)

Comment: The guy you choose ... or _Yvette_.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I mean, we don't actually *know* that she's the only woman running. She's the only woman running who's revealed her gender.

Comment: You're right. And my real name is Annie BTW.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That wasn't meant to be a complaint. No one here is obligated to use their real name or reveal any demographic information about themselves. I was just pointing out there may be other women in the election.

Comment: I didn't think of that possibility. My default impression is that users are male, even the ones who put nice photos of girls to get help :) Your point is made.

Comment: @CalvT븃, I just wanted to give an example of something subjective (aka personal preferences coming from experience). But I guess in the answer it sounds more like a promoted action, therefore downvotes. Bad example.

Answer (score 48):

Okay.

You're not electing anyone that has any substantial or lasting power over your life or your livelihood, nor are you influencing the direction of the site with your picks.

You're *literally* electing janitors.

Diamond moderators primarily handle much of the stuff that regular users simply *can't*, like comment flags, user bannings for irregular voting and poor reviews, and other tasks which are *just* outside of the purview of a user with enough reputation.

You don't have to feel obligated to participate in the process if you don't feel confident that you'd be making a *good* decision, since there's a fair bit to consider from a candidate given what they'd be dealing with.  However you don't have to deprive yourself of information.  [The nomination page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10?tab=nomination) gives you a synopsis, as well as [the answers to community-supplied questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364498/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) will give you a better picture on who's more suitable for the role.  If you want to equip yourself, you can peruse that information.

Remember that **you're not obligated to participate**.  It's not like they're going to enact any policy that causes us to suddenly gain a whole bunch of reputation for no reason.  But hey, if you *do* take the time to participate, you'll be given a couple of badges for your time.

Comment: But these Janitors get a diamond by their name, doesn't that make them like 6 to 8 times better than a normal one?

Comment: @DavyM:  You know how online there's all kinds of content and *stuff* that needs to be moderated and dealt with?  Have you ever visited small-scale websites and seen the amount of raw garbage that those sites produce, and they're relatively *tiny*?  Imagine that on a site that ranks *very* high on search engines and has a large and vast audience.  The garbage heap gets astronomically large and those who are brave enough to go in there to clean it up when *we* can't help are truly heroes.  Still janitors, but heroes no less.

Comment: It is worth noting that a moderator who's *doing their job well*, is just acting as a janitor and isn't going to be a major influence on the site, it's direction, etc.  But in order to do their janitorial tasks they *are* given a lot of powers, and they *can* be used to influence the direction of the site, even though they aren't supposed to be.  Part of the election process is trying to find people trustworthy enough to not do that.  In the same way that a janitor doing their job doesn't impact your company much, but one who abuses their significant access to do things they shouldn't...

Comment: @Servy The power to decide what is garbage or not garbage is definitely an influence on the site. Though, I feel the community does a fairly decent job of it, the amount of garbage audits seems to come up quite often. The mods are thankfully quite helpful in canning the garbage audits in most cases. :)

Comment: Note that these janitors has an inordinate amount of power when it comes to enforcing policy. So rather than janitors is janitors-cum-sheriff-cum-judges-cum-soapboxbearers.

Comment: but but but, the badges!

Answer (score 29):

This is similar to what happens in real world democracy; [~50% voters](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/09/23/ahead-of-debates-many-voters-dont-know-much-about-where-trump-clinton-stand-on-major-issues/) didn't know much about where Trump and Clinton stood on important issues.

Is democracy responsible? Probably not, but [it's the worst form of government, except for all the others](https://richardlangworth.com/worst-form-of-government), there just isn't any good alternative.

Comment: That's just, like, your opinion, man. The parallel is apt though.

Comment: About 78% of those polling statistics are made up though, just like this one.

Comment: An alternative (not necessary a good one) would be mandatory awareness of the candidates? In the voting booth, prepare a documentation on each candidate  + a quiz to check that documentation was read and understood. If quiz is failed, vote is void.

Comment: @Cœur or maybe a literacy test..?

Comment: Except, of course, people whose grandfather voted in the previous moderator election.

Comment: @Cœur The problem is that the people making those quizzes are going to be able to influence the outcome of the elections, like [voter id laws](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/17/us/some-republicans-acknowledge-leveraging-voter-id-laws-for-political-gain.html) and [Gerrymandering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering) are used now.

Comment: There's already a quizz: sort of: that's called "candidates answer your questions"

Comment: @HenningMakholm I suspect that one went over people's heads.